# EditText keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout, keyboard, android-xml

I have a problem in my keyboard type "Decimalnumber",Once I connected my app with my hardware bluetooth, and then start type a number inside EditText, once I hit "Done" from keyboard, it will shows up again the original (the device keyboard). That is bothered and it shouldn't showing the second keyboard any more.
Am not sure what is the reason, but am beginner in android. however edittext xml code is as follow, please any solution would be very thankful.

```
 <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:id="@+id/inputEditView"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:maxLength="3"
        android:hint="Enter pound number "
        android:textColorHint="#FCE4EC"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/green"
        android:background="@drawable/bttnnn"
        android:shadowRadius="10"
        android:shadowColor="#040307"
        android:shadowDx="4"
        android:shadowDy="4"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the InputMethodManager in your onClick, so when you hit your Button "Done", it will hide the keyboard.

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html